# How to get all values from a range?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a range of cells in Excel. It's **C3:E5**. And I want to get all the values in that range, i.e:
`["C3", "C4", "C5", "D3", "D4", "D5", "E3", "E4", "E5"]`. I need it to work with absolutely any range, not just C3:E5.  Cell addresses can be mixed in any order, it is not important. I need to do this specifically with JavaScript capabilities (or with some npm modules for node.js, if they are needed). What can you advise/suggest me?

Comment: are you already using some package like xlsx or something

Comment: If you don't have any existing support library: 1) Split into start end end. 2) Split each into two segments, letters and numbers (using regex for example). 3) Create a function that returns the next column from a given column string (e.g. `A` => `B`, `Z`=> `AA`, `AZ` => `BA`, etc.). For example: Split into characters, increment last's code value, if it went beyond `Z` then set to `A` and increment next, repeat. 4) Write two nested loops, one iterating from first to last column, using your "next column" function to advance, and one iterating from first to last row, using simple incrementation.

Comment: @cmgchess no, .